# Are there any time-series visualization tools available for HDF5 files?

Tags: time-series, data-visualization, software

I have gigabytes of time-series data stored in HDF5 files and while there is the very basic visualization tool available in HDFViewer, I'm interested in knowing if there are rich visualization (charting/graphing) tools available for working with time-series data stored in HDF5 files.

I know that the plethora of Python tools would make "rolling my own" a feasible exercise, it always makes sense to at least survey what is out there. My extensive Google searches indicate time series and HDF5 files are not uncommon, so I'm surprised I'm turning up empty-handed for visualization tools.